# NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.waitFor(J)V with webdriver v2.45.0 and FF v33

Tags: java, selenium

I  have encountered the following error with WebDriver v2.45.0 and Firefox v33.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.waitFor(J)V
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.waitFor(FirefoxBinary.java:222)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.clean(FirefoxBinary.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:99)
```

For Managing classpath I am using Maven. Any ideas?

Comment: Well what version are you *building* against vs the version you're *running* against?

Comment: Sorry, i am not getting your question.

Comment: I am using WebDriver vesion 2.45.0. Previously i was working on 2.39.0 and it was working fine. But for 2.45.0 I am recieving above error.

Comment: It sounds like you may still have bits of 2.39.0 left on the system. I suggest you look very carefully for all jar files etc lying around.

Comment: No. I cleared everything.

Comment: Hmm. Looking on the web, it seems there are similar reports elsewhere, possibly indicating a transitive dependency issue...

Answer (score 1):

Jon Skeet's comments were on the money for me. I looked at the pom's dependency hierarchy in eclipse. PhantomJS was pulling in `selenium-remote-driver` and `selenium-api` 2.41.0. After poking it a bit, seems like, `phantomjsdriver` 1.2.0 conflicts with the firefox driver included in selenium 2.45.0.